# Spring WebのValidationエラーで{0}をフィールド名に置換したい

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring WebのValidation機能を使っています。
エラーメッセージにフィールド名を含めたくて、以下のように実装しています。

### MyForm.java

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
...略...
MyForm{
    /** 名前 */
    @NotEmpty()
    private String name;
}
```

### message.properties

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message = {0}を入力してください
```

MyForm.nameが空の場合、「{0}を入力してください」というメッセージが出てきてしまうのですが、{0}部分をフィールド名の「名前」に置換したいです。

message.propertiesに「name=名前」や「MyForm.name=名前」を定義してもダメでした。

置換するにはどうしたらいいですか？

Spring Boot 2.6.9を使用しています。

Comment: MyFormは@Dataです

Answer (score 1):

問題を再現するコードを記載する必要がありそうです。
私の手元のコードでは想定通り動作しています。

`messages.properties`へ

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message={0}を入力してください
name=名前
```

を追加することにより、期待通り `"名前を入力してください"` が出力されます。

- [サンプル実装コード](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/main/jaso89982)

  - [公式チュートリアル](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)の[コード](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-validating-form-input)をベースにして作成

[`messages.properties`](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/compare/166e8845...a929b52c483)が有る状態と無い状態、`name`プロパティ設定が有る場合無い場合、それぞれで挙動を確認してみてください。